# File does not deploying to jar

Tags: java, javafx

I'm creating simple app with javaFX. Inside my project folder there is text file which I use on UI. Project works , but when I deploy jar there is no this text file inside it. When I run jar file in terminal error happens that file does not exist. I'm not very familiar with creating java UI apps.Below is my code

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("resources/test.txt"));
String str;

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    list.add(str);
}
```

Any help kindly appreciated,

Comment: I guess you will have `pom.xml` in project, If yes can you post pom?

Comment: How are you deploying the jar ?

Comment: @Amogh I don't have pom file.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I'm creating using IntellijIdea I set properties in artifacts

Comment: @support_ms did you unjar the jar to see whether the file is present inside the jar ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are facing is because you are using `FileReader`.

`FileReader` can only be used to read directly a file. If you want to read something which is inside the jar, try to read it using `getResourceAsStream` :

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/resources/test.txt");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
...
```